# String Trim Spaces doesn't work

Tags: c#, string, space, trim, spaces

I have a problem with a String.
The string is like this:

```
string something = "  whatever and something else  ";
```

Now I'm trying to get rid of the spaces at the beginning and at the end like this:

```
something = something.Trim();
```

But that didn't work, I also tried this:

```
something = something.TrimStart();
something = something.TrimEnd();
```

And this:

```
something = something.TrimStart(' ');
something = something.TrimEnd(' ');
```

And this:

```
int lineLength = line.Length;
string LastCharacter = line.Remove(lineLength - 1);
while (LastCharacter == " ")
{
   line = line.Remove(lineLength - 1);
   lineLength = line.Length;
   LastCharacter = line.Remove(lineLength - 1);
}
```

The String is Out of a RichTextBox.

Now I think it could be a problem with the Text formatting or something (I'm in Germany).

Thank you in advance,
tietze111

Comment: What language are you using? `The string is like this: ...` What do you mean by "like"? Is that the *exact* string you have? If not, where are you getting the string from, and what is the value of each character when cast to int?

Comment: .Trim() should work as you expect, you're using it right. The issue is in the text contained in your string.

Comment: Thanks for answering, The Text comes Out of a richTextBox, Sorry that i forgot the Language, it's C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's something that will rip out all white space:

```
 string something = " whatever    ";
 List<char> result = something.ToList();
 result.RemoveAll(c => c == ' ');
 something = new string(result.ToArray());
```

ok, try this for beginning and end only trims:

```
  static string TrimWhitespace(string theString)
    {
        theString = "  some kind of string example ";
        theString = theString.TrimEnd();
        theString = theString.TrimStart();
        // MessageBox.Show(theString, "");
        return theString;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I only want to remove the white spaces at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: I see that your code is using the same TrimEnd and TrimStart functions. I just tested what I posted, it does work. Let me (the group) know if it does not.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but I Don't think this will worl, because I've already tried almost the Same.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was mine mistake, there was a space added after the Trim(), so it couldn't work properly, Thanks for the answers!